# How to work properly with outbounds in WEBRTC?

Tags: java, statistics, webrtc, kurento, outbound

I'm testing the Kurento Room Demo. I'm interested in getting all the possible stats of the videoconference.

I'm running tests with getStats() using getPublisher() and getEndpoint() in every participant, so that way I get info about each bitrate, how much packets are lost...

I only get inboundrtps and endpointrtps that way, but I need as well the Outboundrtps . Could someone help me with how to reach them?

Also, I was looking only at bitrate, latency and packets lost. Is there any other insteresting stat to have in mind when checking the connection quality of each participant?

Thank you so much.

Edit, CODE:

```js
Map<String, Stats> statsMap = null;

try{
statsMap = participant.getPublisher().getEndpoint().getStats();
}catch(Exception e){
break;
}

for (Stats stat : statsMap.values()) {

switch(stat.getType()) {
case inboundrtp:
RTCInboundRTPStreamStats inboundStats = (RTCInboundRTPStreamStats) stat;

System.out.println("Packets Lost: " + inboundStats.getPacketsLost());
System.out.println("Packets Received: " + inboundStats.getPacketsReceived());
System.out.println("BytesReceived: " + inboundStats.getBytesReceived());

System.out.println(inboundStats.getFractionLost());
System.out.println(inboundStats.getJitter());
System.out.println(inboundStats.getMediaTrackId());
System.out.println(inboundStats.getTransportId());
System.out.println(inboundStats.getSsrc());
System.out.println(inboundStats.getRemb());
System.out.println(inboundStats.getTimestamp());
break;
case outboundrtp:
RTCOutboundRTPStreamStats outboundStats = (RTCOutboundRTPStreamStats) stat;
System.out.println(outboundStats.getTargetBitrate());
break;
case endpoint:
EndpointStats statsendpoint = (EndpointStats) stat;
System.out.println("Audio Latency: " + statsendpoint.getInputAudioLatency());
System.out.println("Video Latency: " + statsendpoint.getInputVideoLatency());
break;
default:
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Wanna show us your code?

Comment: Hello @jib. I've edited the post with the code. This way I'm getting inbounds for audio and video, but not the outbounds. I'm getting statsendpoints as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: you will get stats for `Outboundrtps` for an webrtcendpoint having Outboundrtp connection. in your case you are calling `getStats()` for an endpoint which is sending video and not receiving